# Top alignment using longtable and multicolumn

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, longtable, multicolumn

In a largetable, I want to obtain the following:

- All cells vertically aligned to the top
- Left column is horizontally centred, Right column is flushed left
  To be clear in the picture below:
- Alpha should be aligned with One
- Austria should be aligned with 1
  I thought that using p instead of m should do the trick but obviously not, though there are many questions about alignment, I did not find the answer to this specific problem.

Obviously, long table, multicolumn and the small tabular are used here just to have a working example close to what is my actual document.

[image: Obtained table with wrong vertical aligment]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\flushleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| C{1cm} | C{1cm}  | L{3cm} | L{3cm} |}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|C{2cm}|}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    Alpha\\
    Beta\\
    Gamma\\
    Delta
\end{tabular}
}&
 \multicolumn{2}{L{6cm}|}{
 \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    One\\
    Two
\end{tabular}
}
 \\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|C{2cm}|}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    Austria\\
    Belgium
\end{tabular}
}&
 \multicolumn{2}{L{6cm}|}{
 \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    1\\
    2\\
    3
\end{tabular}
}
\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `flushleft` is never inteneded to be used in command form it is the `\begin{flushleft}` environment and like `center` it adds vertical space (as you see) the analogue of `\centering` is `\raggedright`. also you presumably want `p` not `m` columns if you want top alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use `\flushleft` instead of `\raggedright`. `\flushleft` is the begin of the environment `flushleft` which uses the `\trivlist` macro (which is used internally in a lot of places in LaTeX), which happens to introduce some vertical offset.

So to solve your main issue, just use `\raggedright`. The following does fix some more issues and implements a `\mulcol` macro, which is `\multicolumn` with added code to account the `\tabcolsep`s in the skipped columns and the vertical rules (adding it to the width). It assumes that next to every included column there are `2\tabcolsep` of space (which is the default) plus a vertical rule. It also assumes a specific pattern in the second argument, being any tokens then a group specifying a width followed by any more tokens.

The additional issues I fixed are:

- suppress white spaces around the columns in the sub-`tabular`s using `@{}c@{}` or similar.
- using `p` type column for both `L` and `C` (this is actually required to get your vertical alignment right)
- use full space available in the columns put together using `\multicolumn` (this is done with `\mulcol` here, in general you should keep in mind that you also get the space of the stuff in between the columns). This has no big effect on the left aligned columns (you could only see it if you used the full width for the contents), but the centred ones aren't centred compared to the other columns if you forget about this.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\newcommand\mulcol[2]
  {%
    \mulcolA{#1}#2\endmulcolsecarg
  }
\newcommand\mulcolA{}
\long\def\mulcolA#1#2#{\mulcolB{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\mulcolB{}
\long\def\mulcolB#1#2#3#4\endmulcolsecarg
  {%
    \multicolumn
      {#1}
      {%
        #2%
        {%
          \dimexpr
            #3%
            +#1\tabcolsep+#1\tabcolsep-2\tabcolsep
            +#1\arrayrulewidth-\arrayrulewidth
          \relax
        }%
        #4%
      }%
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| C{1cm} | C{1cm}  | L{3cm} | L{3cm} |}
\hline
\mulcol{2}{|C{2cm}|}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    Alpha\\
    Beta\\
    Gamma\\
    Delta
\end{tabular}
}&
 \mulcol{2}{L{6cm}|}{
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    One\\
    Two
\end{tabular}
}
 \\\hline
\mulcol{2}{|C{2cm}|}{
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    Austria\\
    Belgium
\end{tabular}
}&
 \mulcol{2}{L{6cm}|}{
 \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    1\\
    2\\
    3
\end{tabular}
}
\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- instead nesting `tabular` environments inside `multicolumn` cells i would rather use `\makecell` macro from the package of the same name (it is based on `tabular` environment, but for its use the code is shorter).
- since your `longtable` has defined four columns i suspect that the all of them is somewhere used (but not shown in your mwe):

considering above mentioned your table can be written as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array, longtable, makecell}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{| C{1cm} | C{1cm}  | L{3cm} | L{3cm} |}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\makecell[tc]{
    Alpha\\
    Beta\\
    Gamma\\
    Delta}}     &
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\makecell[tl]{
    One\\
    Two}}       \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\makecell[tc]{
    Austria\\
    Belgium}}   &
 \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\makecell[tl]{
    1\\
    2\\
    3}}         \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4   \\
\hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

spurious vertical align of cells contents is removed on the same way as [Skillmon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050/skillmon) do in his answer.

Comment: `\makecell` is in its core just a `tabular` with some code around it. Also your first column (so `\multicolumn{2}{|C{2cm}|}`) is not horizontally centred as you left out the two `\tabcolsep` and the vertical rule in between those two columns. Also in your picture the contents of the first column seem to wander rightwards. This wouldn't have happened if you used `\let\newline\\ ` in the column definitions.